# Objdump -S without assembly

Tags: assembly, objdump

I compiled my c source code and got an elf.

I use "objdump -Sl" but don't need the assembly instructions.

Is there a way to use objdump without the assembly part (or other tool)?

for example, now i get this:

```
**/home/test/src/main.c:764
{
    return OPERATE_ON;
}
else
{
    return OPERATE_OFF;**
 102:   ed88        li  v1,8
 103:   0044 1818   movn    v1,a0,v0
 104:   3042 0000   addiu   v0,v0,0
 108:   c845        sw  v0,20(sp)
 10a:   41a7 1000   lui a3,0x1000
 10e:   3040 02fc   li  v0,764
```

but I only care about the c code:

```
    **/home/test/src/main.c:764
{
    return OPERATE_ON;
}
else
{
    return OPERATE_OFF;**
```

*I know it's possible with tee or regex, but I don't want the assembly instruction at all to make the objdump work faster

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need assembly, just read the source file (`main.c`). `objdump` is a debug tool and by using it you can check what assembly instructions correspond to source lines. If you don't need this functionality, why are you using `objdump` at all?

Comment: I work on a large legacy code with complicated complication and flags.
with objdump I can ignore parts of the code that hasn't been complied for the coonfiguration.